# Hierarchy of priority (if statements in for loops)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, if-statement, for-loop

I am currently taking a Python Databases course offered by Coursera.  The link to the course may be found here:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-databases

I am not asking for anyone to do my homework, just for clarification on how Python 2 reads `for` loops and prioritizes `if` statements.  You can download the appropriate code and XML file I'm parsing here: 
http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/tracks.zip

*Everything that the program is meant to do is outside the scope of this question*.  Inside of the tracks.py program I come across a helper function used for extracting a value of a key inside a dictionary declared in the Library.xml file.  It looks like this:

```
def lookup(d, key):
    found = False
    for child in d:
        if found : return child.text
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key : found = True
    return None
```

At first glance, it didn't make sense to me how the function was checking the `found` boolean and returning the value for the given key **prior** to checking if it was there in the first place.  When I try switching the two statements though, the program doesn't properly read in the data.  ***Why is this?***

If anyone wants me to post how I test and discover why this doesn't work please just let me know and I will add some outputs.

Comment: Python evaluates statements from top to bottom, as most languages do. My guess would just be that the function is supposed to return the _next_ element after the one with the `key`.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  Thanks boss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python evaluates statements from top to bottom, as most languages do. My guess would just be that the function is supposed to return the *next* element after the one with the given `key`.

The `<dict>` elements in your `Library.xml` look like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2015-11-24T11:12:10Z</date>
    ...
```

Those are not really dictionaries in the Python-sense, but just an element `<dict>` containing a *list* of *alternating* `<key>` and `<integer/string/date/whatever>` elements, the latter being the values to the preceding keys. So if you are looking for the value to a given key, you iterate the list `d` until you find the `key` and then return the `text` of the next `child`.

Assuming that those `<dict>` elements are always well formed, you could also use this:

```
def lookup(d, key):
    it = iter(d)
    for child in it:
        if child.tag == 'key' and child.text == key :
            return next(it).text
    return None
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand much better now.  It even made sense as to how I tested the function after switching the statements because it was just printing the "value" (child.text) of the "key" (child.tag) I was looking for.  When switching the statements, I would print values "Name Artist Album..." and was confused as to why it was printing the variable name.  It wasn't.  It was just printing the text for that tag.